# infinite loop c++ with while and vector of pairs

Tags: c++

this program gives infinit loop when i try the input 
1
3 7
1 2
2 3
3 1
i run it manually and it seemed to me that it works , i can't understand why the while gives infinite loop (at least in this case of input)

```
    #include <iostream>

    #include <vector>

#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    unsigned long long T,N , M ,p , m ;
    vector <pair<unsigned long long, unsigned long long > > v;
    cin>>T ;
    for  (unsigned long long i=0 ; i<T;i++)
    {
        v={};
        cin>>N>>M ;
        for (unsigned long long j=0 ; j< N ; j++)
        {
            cin>>p>>m ;
            v.push_back({p,m});

        }
        sort(v.begin(),v.end());

        while (M>=v[0].second)
        {
            while (v[0].first<=v[1].first)
            {
                v[0].first+=1 ;
                M-=v[0].second;

            }
            sort(v.begin(),v.end());

        }


    }
 cout<<"ans"<<v[0].first ;
}
```

can you please tell me what's wrong ??

Comment: Why don't you just debug it?

Comment: Remove `unsigned` and watch everything magically work :-) It's because you're making `M` go past 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to track down the problem without stepping through the debugger is to write values of the key data in important lines.

Also, since you know that you have an infinite loop, add code to limit the number of times the loop gets executed.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

//ADDED: Function to print the contents of the vector.
void print(vector <pair<unsigned long long, unsigned long long > > const& v)
{
   for (auto const& p : v )
   {
      cout << p.first << " " << p.second << " ";
   }
   cout << endl;
}

int main()
{
   unsigned long long T,N , M ,p , m ;
   vector <pair<unsigned long long, unsigned long long > > v;
   cin>>T ;
   for  (unsigned long long i=0 ; i<T;i++)
   {
      v={};
      cin>>N>>M ;
      for (unsigned long long j=0 ; j< N ; j++)
      {
         cin>>p>>m ;
         v.push_back({p,m});
      }
      sort(v.begin(),v.end());

      //ADDED: Limit the number iterations of the loop.
      int count = 0;
      while (M>=v[0].second && count < 20)
      {
         //ADDED: Print the key pieces that control the loop.
         cout << "M: " << M << " v[0].second: " << v[0].second << endl;

         while (v[0].first<=v[1].first)
         {
            v[0].first+=1 ;
            M-=v[0].second;

         }
         sort(v.begin(),v.end());

         //ADDED: Print the vector
         print(v);
         ++count;
      }
   }
   cout<<"ans"<<v[0].first ;
}
```

Here's the output given your input:

```
M: 7 v[0].second: 2
2 3 3 1 3 2 
M: 3 v[0].second: 3
3 1 3 2 4 3 
M: 18446744073709551613 v[0].second: 1
3 2 4 1 4 3 
M: 18446744073709551612 v[0].second: 2
4 1 4 3 5 2 
M: 18446744073709551608 v[0].second: 1
4 3 5 1 5 2 
M: 18446744073709551607 v[0].second: 3
5 1 5 2 6 3 
M: 18446744073709551601 v[0].second: 1
5 2 6 1 6 3 
M: 18446744073709551600 v[0].second: 2
6 1 6 3 7 2 
M: 18446744073709551596 v[0].second: 1
6 3 7 1 7 2 
M: 18446744073709551595 v[0].second: 3
7 1 7 2 8 3 
M: 18446744073709551589 v[0].second: 1
7 2 8 1 8 3 
M: 18446744073709551588 v[0].second: 2
8 1 8 3 9 2 
M: 18446744073709551584 v[0].second: 1
8 3 9 1 9 2 
M: 18446744073709551583 v[0].second: 3
9 1 9 2 10 3 
M: 18446744073709551577 v[0].second: 1
9 2 10 1 10 3 
M: 18446744073709551576 v[0].second: 2
10 1 10 3 11 2 
M: 18446744073709551572 v[0].second: 1
10 3 11 1 11 2 
M: 18446744073709551571 v[0].second: 3
11 1 11 2 12 3 
M: 18446744073709551565 v[0].second: 1
11 2 12 1 12 3 
M: 18446744073709551564 v[0].second: 2
12 1 12 3 13 2 
ans12
```

As you can see, the value of M becomes very large. That happens when `(M -
 v[0].second)` is a negative value.

You can fix it by making `M` a signed type. Whether that is the appropriate solution for you is difficult to tell from your post. I trust that you will be able to resolve the issue one way or another.

Comment: you're right it gives the appropriate solution when i remove 'unsigned' but i dont understand why (M - v[0].second) matters , i mean M is still >=0 and the third output should be M=0 ! so it compares 0 to 1 and exits

Comment: @user6465283, that's when stepping through a debugger might be useful.

Comment: well , when i debug it just shows that M takes 18446744073709551613 instead of 0 and what i asked is why it takes such a value because an unsigned can take 0 .

Comment: Add a line to print `M` and `v[0].second` just before the line `M-=v[0].second;`. That will be helpful.